# how to Find files on Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, permission-denied

there is a file I have to find, `context.xml`. I tried `find / -name context.xml` on terminal, but I got many `Permission denied`.

Then I tried `sudo find / -name context.xml`, and I was told to enter password. After entering that password, I still got many `Operation not permitted`.

I also tried to restart my Mac, then tried that two commands. But, still the same error. Could anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do sudo, the Terminal application itself may not have sufficient privileges on newer versions of MacOS.  See https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/ for more details.